# Using Angular in one of the node.js a project, should I be using a new HTML framework along with it like Foundation Zurb or Bootstrap?

Tags: node.js, angular, bootstrap-4, zurb-foundation

Using Angular in a node.js project, should I be using a new HTML framework along with it like Foundation Zurb or Bootstrap?

Or does angular also handle the job of Foundation Zurb / Bootstrap? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, you can use either Foundation or Bootstrap in an Angular app.

If you use Bootstrap you will need to use one of the Angular-compatible versions such as [ngx-bootstrap](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap) or [ng-bootstrap](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap) because normal Bootstrap requires jQuery.

The long answer is that with an Angular app you are free to use whatever CSS framework that you choose.  The only limitation would be if the framework utilizes JavaScript to modify the DOM as that may cause conflicts with Angular's rendering engine.

Another option to consider is [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/), an Angular-specific option that might be a better fit for your project.